# Custom Plugin - Query CPT - Display Results

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, wp-query

This code is going into a sample Plugin I am creating as a test using CPT and print them to a Page.

I have been trying to get print_r() to give me an object. The custom post types are posting - verified. The data is being stored in MySQL - verified. Thus the post type is registering.

Please provide me with a new set of eyes to tell me what I am missing in my query.

```
add_action('init', 'all_custom_post_types');

function all_custom_post_types() {

  $types = array(
    // Pledge Items
    array('the_type' => 'testimonial',
    'single' => 'Testimonial',
    'plural' => 'Testimonials'));

  foreach ($types as $type) {

  $the_type = $type['the_type'];
  $single = $type['single'];
  $plural = $type['plural'];

  $labels = array(
  'name' => _x($plural, 'post type general name'),
  'singular_name' => _x($single, 'post type singular name'),
  'add_new' => _x('Add New', $single),
  'add_new_item' => __('Add New '. $single),
  'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$single),
  'new_item' => __('New '.$single),
  'view_item' => __('View '.$single),
  'search_items' => __('Search '.$plural),
  'not_found' => __('No '.$plural.' found'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('No '.$plural.' found in Trash'),
  'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );

  $args = array(
  'labels'             => $labels,
  'public'             => true,
  'has_archive'        => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui'            => true,
  'query_var'          => true,
  'rewrite'            => true,
  'capability_type'    => 'post',
  'hierarchical'       => false,
  'menu_position'      => 5,
  'supports'           => array('title','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields','excerpt'));

register_post_type($the_type, $args);

  }

}

////////////////////////

function testimonials_list() {
    if (is_page('9595')) {

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'Testimonials'
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    print_r($the_query);
endwhile;

    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','testimonials_list');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'Testimonials'
     ) );
```

Looks like you probably just need to change that to :

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial' )
);
```

You need to use the name you created it with when looking at post_type

Comment: Check your bracket count after making the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue currently is that `pre_get_posts` fires for every query within a request. You're creating an infinite loop which terminates with a fatal out of memory error. If you [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), you should see the error message.

Your `testimonials_list` function fires for the first query on your page, and the condition `is_page('9595')` is met, and you create a new query, `$the_query`. This in turn fires the same `testimonials_list` function, which also meets the `is_page('9595')` conditional, and creates a new query. This happens over and over until PHP runs out of memory.

The answer involves an additional check, like [`is_main_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query), and/or [`remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to remove the action after it runs once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this. I think I am getting closer: add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cv_testimonials_list');
function cv_testimonials_list($query) {
    if ($query->is_page('9595') && $query->is_main_query()) {
  gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', false);
  $args = array (
 'post_type'              => 'testimonial',
 'post_status'            => 'published',
 'pagination'             => true,
 'posts_per_page'         => '10',
 'order'                  => 'DESC',
 'orderby'                => 'date',
);
 // The Query
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  print_r($query);
 return;
    }
}

Comment: The problem I am facing now is the header is populating with the content of the query and not the_content area of the Page.